# Drag from a ScrollPane to a target outside of the ScrollPane?

Tags: flash, drag-and-drop, scrollpane

I haven't been able to find a non-hack way to use Drag and Drop with the AS3 ScrollPane component.

Here's what I'm doing:

I create a container mc, which I then add a bunch of children to.  The children are what I want to drag.

However, dragging is constrained to the boundaries of the ScrollPane.  This seems to me like a limitation of the ScrollPane component.

I know it can be worked around with attaching a dupe mc to the cursor pos, then manipulating other mcs on mouse up, but... doesn't that seem kind of lame to everybody?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Scrollpane's but id try to make a trigger when u drag something to the boundary of the scrollpane based on x.y pos you call a function to remove the item from the scrollpane and add it to the parent frame.